# undefined reference to `main' in make

Tags: c++, makefile

Following is my Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -c -g -W -O3 -Wall -Werror -Wshadow \
-Wno-long-long -Wpointer-arith -D_REENTRANT \
-D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DLINUX2 \
-I ./lib_acl_cpp/include
BASE_PATH=./acl
LDFLAGS = -L$(BASE_PATH)/lib_acl_cpp/lib -l_acl_cpp \
-L$(BASE_PATH)/lib_protocol/lib -l_protocol \
-L$(BASE_PATH)/lib_acl/lib -l_acl \
-lpthread
test: main.o
   g++ -o main.o $(LDFLAGS)
main.o: main.cpp
   g++ $(CFLAGS) main.cpp -o main.o
```

Following is the main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout<<"hello";
   return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In 
function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
```

Why is it so?

Comment: After changing the test to g++ -o test main.o $(LDFLAGS) or g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS), I am getting " missing separator. Stop."

Comment: Take care to replace spaces with tabulators when using cut&paste from the code here.

Comment: It helped me out. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the rule for your executable to

```
test: main.o
   g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: Now it gives this error: " missing separator. Stop." on g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

Comment: Make sure to use tabs for indentation in makefiles. Copying the above snippet will insert spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your rule for `test` is wrong: it overwrites `main.o`. should be

```
g++ -o test main.o $(LDFLAGS)
```

Or you can make use of the [built-in variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html):

```
g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: Now it is giving me the following error:" missing separator.  Stop." on g++ -o test main.o $(LDFLAGS)

Comment: Replaced spaces with tabs.

Answer (score 1):

The line creating the executable is wrong.

```
test: main.o
   g++ -o main.o $(LDFLAGS)
```

Here you are telling to g++ to generate an executable `main.o` starting from no object modules. The C runtime correctly whines that it cannot find any `main` function; even if it managed to spit out an executable, it would overwrite your `main.o` object module.

What you probably want is:

```
test: main.o
    g++ -o test main.o $(LDFLAGS)
```

which means "generate an executable `test` using the `main.o` object module".